# Julia, MethodError: no method matching

Tags: julia, matching, abstract-type

I wanted to test how abstract type works in "strcutres", so I created a struct below with a constructor, however, the return message displays "ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Rect(::Int64)".

I don't know which part went wrong, although the parameter "5" that I used fits the definition of the constuctor which is a single integer input. Thank you.

```
abstract type Shape{T<:Integer,F<:AbstractFloat} end
export Shape

struct Rect{T,F} <: Shape{T,F}
    a::T
    b::T
    c::T
    v::F
    function Rect{T,F}(a::T) where {T<:Integer, F<:AbstractFloat}
        b = 10;
        c = 10;
        v = a*b*c;
        return new(a,b,c,v)
    end
end

function main()

    vol = Rect(5).v;

    println(vol)

end

main()
```

It should return a product of a, b and c with only a being the input variable.

Comment: With only an argument of type `T`, how would the constructor know which type is `F`? Try `Rect{Int64,Float64}(5).v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the appropriate constructor.
You should do:

```
julia> Rect{Int,Float64}(5)
Rect{Int64, Float64}(5, 10, 10, 500.0)
```

Other option is to add the constructor to your struct:

```
function Rect{T}(a::T) where {T<:Integer}
    Rect{Int,Float64}(a)
end
```

Once you add the constructor you can do:

```
julia> Rect{Int}(5)
Rect{Int64, Float64}(5, 10, 10, 500.0)
```

Or you can also define:

```
Rect(a::Int) =  Rect{Int,Float64}(a)
```

and have

```
julia> Rect(5)
Rect{Int64, Float64}(5, 10, 10, 500.0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After adding the constructor, the line Rect{Int,Float64}(a) is calling the constructor function Rect{T,F}(a::T) ... I previously defined?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could also define for convenience something like ` Rect(a::Int) =  Rect{Int,Float64}(a)`